# Double Stub Matching Impedance

Tags: transmission-line, smith-chart

I'm trying to understand the double stub matching impedance using Smith Chart.

Here is the diagram for the double stub impedance:

[image]

The impedance on the right has to appear purely resistive.
So admittance \$Y_2=-jb'\$ and admittance \$Y_b=1+jb'\$
and the admittance at \$Y_1\$ is elected to be at \$3\lambda /8\$. Why is this distance chosen to be \$3\lambda /8\$?
And to get the impedance at this location isn't it enough that I rotate \$Y_b\$ by \$270^0\$, why do I have to rotate the whole circle by 270?